# Учебная задача по javascript

Tags: javascript

Задача: Создайте функцию find(arr, value), которая ищет в массиве arr значение value и возвращает его номер, если найдено или -1, если не найдено.

Вот мое решение

```
arr = [ 3, "test", 2, 1.5, false ];

    function find(array, value) {
        for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] === value){
            return i;
            break;
            }
        return -1;
        }
    }

    var result = find(arr, 2);
    alert (result);
```

не могу понять, что не так и почему не срабатывает, каждый раз возвращает -1.

Comment: array.indexOf(value)

Comment: да, тоже можно)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

return -1 в цикле стоит. А должен после него.

Comment: break можно убрать, т.к. return означает немедленный выход из функции и передачу значения.

Comment: понятно, спасибо. и еще такой вопрос, не подскажите, как в инструменте разработчика поставить брейкпоинт в цикле так, чтобы можно было смотреть что происходит на каждой итерации?

Comment: К сожалению, пользуюсь firefox + firebug. Но по вашей теме что-то нашел: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints. Вообще отладкой кода больше в голове занимаюсь. Ну и стандартные способы, типа alert(x), console.log()

Comment: хорошо, спасибо)